# Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.*****.******" doesn't include the currently selected device "****’s MacBook Pro"

Tags: ios, xcode

I've recently got the new M1 MacBook Pro and have been developing my app on it using Xcode. It has been working fine for a few weeks and whenever I build it, I would build my SwiftUI iOS app to my Mac using the iOS>My Mac(Designed For iPad) option. Today when I tried to build my app to my Mac, I just so happened to be not connected to the internet, and then I got the error "Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.******.******" doesn't include the currently selected device "****’s MacBook Pro" (identifier ********-****-****-****-***********)." I checked in the Accounts tab in my apple developer account and my MacBook Pro's UUID and name were on there. It builds fine and runs fine on my phone, but won't work on my Mac. Could anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: Hi, yes, so I fixed this problem by turning off "Open using Rosetta", then all was good!

Answer (score 8):

this issue might be due to running Xcode with Rosetta, if that is so you can go to the Applications folder find Xcode, and right-click on the icon to open the menu, then click on get info, in the info panel uncheck the 'Open using Rosetta' option